# Cannot test the false path of canActivate() - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can anybody help me with testing the false path of my canActivate function that determines the AuthGuard of my app?

It appears that I am having trouble with faking an `RouterStateSnapshot`...

**Guard**

```
canActivate(
      next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    console.log(next);
    console.log(state);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
```

Comment: It would be great to have the guard, too.

Comment: Whoops. There you go @trichetriche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fullfill all of the conditions to pass the falsy test :

```
it('should return false', () => {
  spyOn(guard['authService'], 'getStoredToken').and.returnValue('');

  expect(guard.canActivate(null, { url: 'foo' } as any)).toEqual(false);
});
```

Comment: I managed to get it working differently to you. Would you have a look at my submitted answer below and see if I've done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution...

```
const next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
const state: any = {url: ''};
const queryParams = {queryParams: {returnUrl: ''}};

it('should return false and not navigate', () => {
    // Set token as '' as this is what would be returned by 'getToken' function
    localStorage.setItem('token', '');
    expect(guard.canActivate(next, state)).toEqual(false);
    expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['login'], queryParams);
  });
```

Comment: You indeed do something "wrong" : unit tests are supposed to test a *unit* : this means that they rely on nothing but the unit itself. In your case, you rely on your implementation of your auth service, that fetches the token : this should be mocked, instead of you fixing the token in the local storage, you should use a spy to mock the behavior.

Comment: And you expect not to navigate but test if you navigated correctly : this is probably a typo, but worth the mention !

Comment: Ah yes, hard to say that we want to go back to login and not forwards to the admin-only page.

Comment: `and navigate to login` ?

Comment: It's been a long day, leave me alone :P